# When opening my app from another app the flags I set for the intents are ignored

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have two apps, `AppA` and `AppB`. In `AppA` I open up `AppB` with following intent:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setPackage("AppB PackageName");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    intent.setData("some data"));
    startActivity(intent);
```

Then `AppB` open up as expected. In `AppB` I now want to navigate through following activities:

```
ActivityA -> ActivityB -> ActivityC -> ActivityD
```

and in ActivityC I initialize a fragment. I'm opening **all** the activities with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, IncomingAppRequestView.class);
//intent.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);   
//intent.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);   
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
openView(intent);
```

with the intention that in `ActivityC` when processing is done the application should open back up `AppA`.

```
Intent intent = getContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(redirectPackageName);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

`AppA` is opening up as expected. And triggers onNewIntent in `AppA`. But when clicking on history button in Android and choose `AppB` again it opens `AppB` with `ActivityC` and not `ActivityA`.

If I choose to use *finishAffinity()* to open AppA again instead of the *getLaunchIntentForPackage* it opens up AppB with ActivityA. But the I won't be able to provide parameters from AppB back to AppA which I need in order to know what the results were in AppB.

What am I missing? Why isn't the stack of activities cleared? Why do I come back to the wrong activity? Specifying parent is not an option since I might come into ActivityC from another scenario and thus want to navigate to ActivityB. So clearing all history is only valid in this scenario when coming from another app.

The log also shows that I come into onResume in ActivityC and the fragment.

EDIT:

I actually missed an activity, so the navigation is:

```
ActivityA -> ActivityB -> ActivityC -> ActivityD
```

AppB´s manifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.myapp">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name_short"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".views.activities.SplashActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name_short"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".views.activities.ActivityA"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name_short"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:scheme="@string/URI_SCHEME_NAME" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".views.activities.ActivityB"
        android:parentActivityName=".views.activities.ActivityA"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

    <activity android:name=".views.activities.ActivityC"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

    <activity android:name=".views.activities.ActivityD"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />


</application>

</manifest>
```

AppA´s manifest looks like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.nexusgroup.personal.ebberod.bank">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:scheme="ebberod" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".LoggedInActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Post the manifest for both apps please.

Comment: I updated my question with the manifest.

Comment: You only posted one of the manifests. Please post the other.

Comment: Sorry, I've added the other manifest.

Comment: Why are you using `singleTask` launch mode? What is the reason for this? This is causing most of your problem.

Comment: Well, the thought was that ActivityA would be a single task, like top root. But I can try without it (or singletop).

Comment: The correct way to handle this to use fragments. If the user stays on the same level from the perspective of navigation then use fragments. Is the user is supposed to be able to go back use an Activity. Stick to this and your life will be much simpler. To summarize: all those activities in AppB should be Fragments.  And instead of opening a new activity you should just switch to the next fragment. That way you preserve the back stack in exactly the way you want without having to mess around with the navigation stack - that always tends to lead to problems.

Comment: Yes, in that simple scenario that you describe. But this is only one scenario described above. From ActivityB you should be able to navigate to ActivityA on back, from c -> b, and so on. It's just when you enter the last one you should ignore the stack.